# Windows 7 adds a Program Files (x86) directory with empty Microsoft XDE\8.1 subdirectory to empty HDD

Tags: windows-7

I recently formatted and repartitioned a small HDD that I have on my PC, and after rebooting the OS (Windows 7 Professional) I can see that Windows has added a Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1 directory on this disk.

It does not even allow me to delete the "Program Files (x86)" directory. It looks like as shown in below screen shot.

What can be the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1` folder seems to belong to `Windows Phone Emulator` (see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/notime/archive/2013/04/21/shortcut-to-start-windows-phone-8-emulator.aspx) article). Do you have it installed?

Comment: thanks @ge0rdi, I do indeed have it installed. I guess it has something to do with this.